# Min and Max length of a column in SQL

Tags: sql, maxlength

I have a table with two columns

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_Orders]
(
    [OrderID] [bigint] NOT NULL IDENTITY(500000, 1)
    ,[OrderDate] [date] NULL
)
```

I would like to know the min and max length of column OrderID
How many characters can it store?

Since ident is starting from 500000, the min(length) would be 6, and how can I find the max length?

Comment: Its the size of bigint isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Size of `bigint` is 8 bytes. It can store -2^63 (-9,223,372,036,854,775,808) to 2^63-1 (9,223,372,036,854,775,807). So maximum length of OrderID will be 19 (9,223,372,036,854,775,807).

Comment: Thank you @Kazi Mohammad Ali Nur. And was I correct about the minimum length? 6?

Comment: Definitely. OrderID will start from500000 which is 6 digits.